# Error 'WARNING' message when using Extractor from Deepbrain library

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, extractor, nibabel

I receive this error (as follow) when trying to use Etractor from deepbrain library:

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myname\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deepbrain\extractor.py:19: FastGFile.**init** (from tensorflow.python.platform.gfile) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.gfile.GFile.

I am using a old version of the libray, yes?
How to solve that?

```
import nibabel as nb
from deepbrain import Extractor as ext

img = nb.load("imgpath").get_fdata()

# `prob` will be a 3d numpy image containing probability 
# of being brain tissue for each of the voxels in `img`
prob = ext.run(img)
```

Comment: It means exactly what is says, the library is deprecated and need to use the latest one.

Comment: Yes. You r right. Better to change my last question.

Comment: You are not necessarily running an old version of the library. It seems the library itself is using an older version of TensorFlows FastGFile API. If they haven't upgraded the code yet than there's nothing you can do except for ignoring this warning.